# Determine if Active Directory object is new or updated using DirectorySynchronization

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm running a query in Active Directory and polling for changes using the [DirectorySynchronization class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysynchronization(v=vs.110).aspx).

I need to determine which kind of operation happened for the object since the last query, i.e. if the object was created, modified or deleted.

I can easily determine if the object was deleted by checking the "isDeleted" property (which requires setting the `Tombstone` property on the searcher), but I don't know how to determine if the object is new or modified. Ideally, I would like to do that just by looking at the query results.

Here's a (quick and dirty) code example:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string[] propertiesToLoad = new[] { "distinguishedName", "isDeleted" };
        using (DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://someDC.domain.com/DC=domain,DC=com"))
        using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root, "(objectClass=user)", propertiesToLoad)) {
            searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            searcher.Tombstone = true;
            if (File.Exists("cookie.bin")) {
                searcher.DirectorySynchronization = new DirectorySynchronization(
                    DirectorySynchronizationOptions.ObjectSecurity,
                    LoadCookie("cookie.bin"));
            } else {
                searcher.DirectorySynchronization = new DirectorySynchronization(
                    DirectorySynchronizationOptions.ObjectSecurity);
            }
            foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll()) {
                if (result.Properties.Contains("isDeleted") && (bool)(result.Properties["isDeleted"][0])) {
                    // object is deleted
                } else {
                    // HOW TO DETERMINE IF OBJECT WAS CREATED OR MODIFIED?
                }
            }
            SaveCookie("cookie.bin", searcher.DirectorySynchronization);
        }
    }

    static byte[] LoadCookie(string path) {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            return (byte[])formatter.Deserialize(fs);
        }
    }

    static void SaveCookie(string path, DirectorySynchronization sync) {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)) {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(fs, sync.GetDirectorySynchronizationCookie());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @JasonMArcher: I put back the "directory-synchronization" tag, as it refers to the mechanism I'm using to retrieve the changes, not to the class or the property of the search object.

Comment: Per your question, you created it because you are using that class.  This is a bad tag because it is too focused to be useful in categorization.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the whenCreated and whenChanged properties.